# Passing a parameter to a executable program at runtime

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am using Python Os.System("path/xyz.exe",parameter)

```
    exe_file = "E:\selenium-python\\autopilot.exe -config" + argument
    os.system(exe_file)
```

the above code works fine but now for my program purpose, I want to use this same running .exe file throughout the program, now the issue is I want to pass the argument at run time.

is there any way in python to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the config file name as a command-line argument for your python script:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='test')
parser.add_argument('--config', help='autopilot config file')
args = parser.parse_args()

exe_file = "E:\selenium-python\\autopilot.exe -config" + args.config
os.system(exe_file)
```

Comment: I want something like this 
os.system("C:/program/xyz.exe")
and then in the next line, I want to pass an argument

Comment: so "xyz" (the program name) is the dynamic part given on run time?

Comment: No, The dynamic part is the argument that I will pass in the next line. And the issue is I don't know how to pass an argument after we call .exe file using Os.system()

Comment: can you explain why do you need to pass the argument AFTER the program already started?

Comment: I am automating a webpage that move through several pages and print every page it moves and calling to OS.system() every time I move from one page to another create a new instance of already running application which makes it a memory consuming task.  So I want to use the already running program just passes a new argument(File name is the dynamic variable that I want to pass as argument)

Comment: ok, generally, programs accept command-line arguments only when they are launched. the standard way of daemons to accept requests after they are up is via a network port, something like a REST API. this is very application-specific. for example, in the Unix world many apps are accepting signals for reloading their config.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use the 2 methods from AUTOIT

https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/StdinWrite.htm
https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/StdoutRead.htm

To read and write message between process.

In python, you can read using

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    print(line)
```

and also:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write(str(99) + '\n')
```

Autoit already has example on the link I've gave for communication between process. The python can simply read and write from it's own process STDIN and STDOUT. The autoit script will actually read and write to another process STDIN and STDOUT.